# Enabled and Disabled Previous button loads at The same Time via Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I used The code below  to display information to database via **Reactjs**. When I click the next button, it works. No what to add previous button.
Here is what am trying to do.

On the First data load, I need to disable the Previous button and on Next data load, I need to enable the previous button.
 The problem am having is that both enabled and disabled previous button are loaded at the same time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>


<style>

.pic{
background:blue; color:white;}
</style>


<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">




class Application extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state = {rec : [
     { "name" : "Tony", "Age" : "18"},
     { "name" : "John", "Age" : "21" },
     { "name" : "Luke", "Age" : "78" },
     { "name" : "Mark", "Age" : "90" },
     { "name" : "Jame", "Age" : "87" },
     { "name" : "Franco", "Age" : "34" },
     { "name" : "Franco", "Age" : "34" },
     { "name" : "Biggard", "Age" : "19" },
     { "name" : "tom", "Age" : "89" },
   ],    
   limit : 2
};
   this.next = this.next.bind(this);
   this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);

 }


next() {
   const recLength = this.state.rec.length;
   const currentLimit = this.state.limit;
   if (currentLimit < recLength) {

      this.setState({ limit: currentLimit + 2 });
   }

 }


previous() {
   const recLength = this.state.rec.length;
   const currentLimit = this.state.limit;
   if (currentLimit < recLength) {

      this.setState({ limit: currentLimit - 2 });
   }
}


render() {

//let prevLink = parseInt( 2) - 1;

//let prevRec = 2;
const prevRec = this.state.rec.length;


   return <div className="container">

     <div>
       <h3>List of Records</h3>
       <ul>
         {this.state.rec.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((obj, i) => 
             <li key={i}>{obj.name} - {obj.Age}</li>
         )}
       </ul>
     </div>



                <ul className="pager">

<li>
                        {prevRec == 2 ? // Disable previous button if showing the first two loaded Data
                            <a >Disabled Previous</a>
                            :
                            <span>Disabled Previous </span>
                        }
                    </li>





                    <li>
                        {prevRec > 2 ? // Enable Active Previous button on next data load
                            <a onClick={this.previous}>Enable Previous </a>
                            :
                            <span>Enable Previous</span>
                        }
                    </li>


<a  onClick={this.next}>
          Next
      </a> 
                </ul>


   </div>;
 }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve the Problem. I first check the records in the array  and discovered that I have 9 records already 
and then I have to get the length of records in  the array as per

```
const prevRec = this.state.rec.length;
```

Finally, the code below solve my issue

```
const prevRec = const prevRec = this.state.rec.length;


{prevRec <= 9 &&  // Disable Previous if records in the array is less than or equal to 9
        <h2>
         <a>Disable Previous</a>
        </h2>
      }

{prevRec > 9 &&
        <h2>
         <a onClick={this.previous}>Enable Previous</a>
        </h2>
      }
```